# dragon drop operation in tables using cocoa

Tags: cocoa

how to write an application to implement the dragon drop operation in tables using cocoa?

Comment: Do not drop dragons on the table, they don't like it! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Look at the table view delegate and data source. They have methods with "drag" and "drop" in their names. Implement those and you're golden.

There's a lot of documentation on "Drag and Drop" in Apple's developer docs at http://developer.apple.com

Don't try to code without the documentation. There be Tygers.